# Recursive function for going through unknown DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

I am learning about js **DOM** and I want to make a **recursive function** that I could use to **go through all nodes in any DOM**. I made it, but I can not figure out why my first attempt is not working:

**HTML**

```js
function mostrarNodosV2(node) {
  console.log(node.nodeName);
  if (node.firstElementChild != null) {
    node = node.firstElementChild;
    mostrarNodosV2(node);
  }

  if (node.nextElementSibling != null) {
    node = node.nextElementSibling;
    mostrarNodosV2(node);
  }

}

mostrarNodosV2(document);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Exercise IV</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Just a header</h1>
  <p>Nice paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Im just an element list on an unordered list</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

The flow is next:

1. **document node**.
2. we repeat the function with his first child: **head node**.
3. we repeat the function with his first child: **meta node**.
4. because of 'meta' has no childs, we repeat the function with his next
   sibling: **title node**.
5. because of 'title' has no childs or next sibling, we end the
   function where node=title, we should end the function where node =
   meta, and we should continue checking the next sibling of head: **body node**.

**Instead of that**, if you debug or check the console you will see that browser repeats the section:

```html
if (node.nextElementSibling != null) {
    node = node.nextElementSibling;
    mostrarNodosV2 (node);
}
```

Where node = meta, and **so we get two 'TITLE' printed on console**. Then it goes as it should have gone, and we get the 'body' node. The same problem happens with the 'LI' element.

So, I do not want another solution, I just did it, I just want to know why I go back to that 'if', because I don't get it.

If you debug it on developer tools it would be easier to understand.

Comment: I did it -> `[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('*') ).forEach( ...`

Comment: @adeneo that's not the point, the point is to debug the recursive function OP already has.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts which is why it was a comment not an answer, and **relevant**.

Comment: @DavidBarker not really. This question is tagged `recursion` whereas adeneo's snippet is _iterative_.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yet somehow it is still not an answer, and it is still relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your recursive function repeated nodes was because you reassigned `node`. Let's step through the function ourselves:

```
document -> has a child
  html -> has a child
    head -> has a child
      meta -> has no child, has a sibling
        title -> has no child or sibling
    head -> head has been overwritten with meta, which has a sibling
      title -> has no child or sibling
  html -> html has been overwritten with head, which has a sibling
    body -> has a child
      h1 -> has no child, has a sibling
        p -> has no child, has a sibling
          ul -> has a child
            li -> has no child or sibling
          ul -> ul has been overwritten with li, which has no sibling
    body -> body has been overwritten with h1, which has a sibling
      ...
```

So now you understand why it's bad to overwrite the function argument.

If you would like a more robust approach, here is how I would have written a recursive DOM traversal function:

```
function mostrarNodosV2(node) {
  if (node == null) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(node.nodeName);

  mostrarNodosV2(node.firstElementChild);
  mostrarNodosV2(node.nextElementSibling);
}

mostrarNodosV2(document);
```

The only difference here is I'm checking the node validity one recursion deeper than you were for each node, which reduces the verbosity of your approach.

Comment: Thanks again, that helped. I will check it as the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you are re-assigning `node` variable, try this:

```
function mostrarNodosV2(node) {
    console.log(node.nodeName);
    if (node.firstElementChild != null) {
        var child = node.firstElementChild;
        mostrarNodosV2(child);
    }
    if (node.nextElementSibling != null) {
        var sibling = node.nextElementSibling;
        mostrarNodosV2(sibling);
    }
}
mostrarNodosV2(document);
```

Comment: no, wasn't mine; that worked! I still need to know what is going on, but knowing where was the problem would help me a lot. thanks!

Comment: Personally I believe this deserves upvotes (which I gave one), but if I had to guess, I'd say it was downvoted because you didn't explain why the behavior occurred and provided a solution without the requested explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement your own, the [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) DOM Level 2 API allows traversal, choosing a custom start node and changing the direction.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, but I think OP approached this as a learning exercise rather than writing the function out of necessity.